# How can I replace only the last occurence of an number in a string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would you change this:

```
a-10-b-19-c
```

into something like this:

```
a-10-b-20-c
```

using regular expressions in Javascript?

It should also change this:

```
a-10-b-19
```

into this:

```
a-10-b-20
```

The only solution I've found so far is:

- reverse the original string -> `"c-91-b-01-a"`
- find the first number (with `\d+`) -> `"91"`
- reverse it -> `"19"`
- turn in into a number (parseInt) -> `19`
- add 1 to it -> `20`
- turn it into a string again (toString) -> `"20"`
- reverse it again -> `"02"`
- replace the original match with this new number -> `"c-02-b-01-a"`
- reverse the string -> `"a-10-b-20-c"`

I was hoping someone on SO would have a *simpler* way to do this... Anyone?

Comment: To find the number you are looking you can use following regex: -\d

Comment: @Shawn: See my updated post http://stackoverflow.com/a/12516204/846190

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple way.

```
var str = 'a-10-b-19-c';
str = str.replace(/(\d*)(?=(\D*)?$)/, +str.match(/(\d*)(?=(\D*)?$)/)[0]+1);
```

`+str.match` finds 19, adds 1 to it and returns 20. The `+` makes sure the answer is an int. `str.replace` finds 19 and replaces it with what `str.match` returned which was 20.

Explanation

- `(\d*)` - matches any digits
- `(?=...)` - positive lookahead, doesn't change regex position, but makes sure that pattern exists further on down the line.
- `(\D*)?$` - it doesn't have to, but can match anything that is not a number multiple times and then matches the end of the string

Comment: Care to explain a bit? I've never seen `?` used like that before (just  after an opening parenthesis)

Comment: Nice solution. For this, it would be useful to create a RegExp.

Comment: @Shawn - The `(?=` is a look-ahead assertion. `x(?=y)` succeeds only if `x` is followed by `y`, but `y` is not part of the match result.

Comment: What does the `+` before `str.match` do?

Comment: @Shawn - The `+` forces the outcome to be an int. So when you +1 it actually adds instead of adding to the string. If it is a string and you did +1, it would give this result. `19 + 1 = 191`

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, this will not work for input like the following: `a-10-b-19` Correct? And I would have to use `str.replace(/(\d*)(?=-\D*?$|$)/, +str.match(/(\d*)(?=-\D*?$|$)/)[0]+1);`

Comment: Correct. By changing the regex to `/(\d*)(?:(?=\D*?$)|$)/` it would work for either. The `(?:..)` is a non-capturing group so it is not part of the match. Then `|$` means or end of the string.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I couldn't have found this myself as I was missing 3 regexp features.. Could you edit your answer to add the `|$` and then I will accept it?

Comment: @Shawn - I changed the regex so it doesn't need the `|$` anymore. Either way works, but this way is the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

```
//replaces last digit sequences with 20
'a-10-b-19-c'.replace(/\d+(?!.*\d+)/, '20')
```

`/` --> Start of regex

`\d+` --> Match any digit (one or more)

`(?!.*\d+)` --> negative look ahead assertion that we cannot find any future (one or more) digits

`/` --> end of regex

Edit: Just reread about adding,

Can use match for that, e.g.:

```
    var m ='a-10-b-19-c'.match(/\d+(?!.*\d+)/);
    'a-10-b-19-c'.replace(/\d+(?!.*\d+)/, parseInt(m[0]) + 1);
```

Comment: Why do you use parens around the `\d+` in the `match` but not in the `replace`?

Comment: @Shawn I removed them, they don't really mean anything in this context.  Similar (but not really) to how 1+2+3 results in the same value as 1+(2+3).

Comment: @Shawn If you want to learn more about parens and regexs read up on "grouping."

Answer (score 1):

Here's an even simpler one:

```
str.replace(/(.*\D)(\d+)/, function(s, pfx, n) {return pfx + ((+n) + 1)})
```

or

```
str.replace(/.*\D(\d+)/, function(s, n) {return s.slice(0, -n.length) + ((+n) + 1)})
```

Neither of these will work if the number is the first thing in the string, but this one will:

```
(' ' + str).replace(/.*\D(\d+)/,
                    function(s, n) {
                      return s.slice(1, -n.length) + ((+n) + 1)
                    })
```

(Why does Javascript need three different substring functions?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way I can think of:

```
var str = 'a-10-b-19-c';
var arr = str.split('-');
arr[3] = parseInt(arr[3]) + 1;
str = arr.join('-');
```

**Edit to explain:**

The `split()` method takes the parameter (in this case the hyphen) and breaks it up into an array at each instance it finds. If you type `arr` into your JavaScript console after this part runs you'll get `["a", "10", "b", "19", "c"]`

We know that we need to change the 4th item here, which is accessed by index 3 via `arr[3]`. Each piece of this array is a string. If you try to increment a string by 1 it will simply concatenate the string with a 1 (JS uses the `+` for addition and concatenation) so you need to use `parseInt()` to make it an integer before you do the addition.

Then we use the `join()` method to glue the array back together into a string!

Comment: That would only work if the output is always string, number, string number string, which might not be the case.

Comment: How do you know that we need to change the 4th item? He said "last number", implying that there can be any number of them. Maybe he should have given more than one example so you'd know the extent of variation possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var str='a-10-b-19-c';
var pattern=/\d+/g;
var matches=pattern.exec(str);
var last=matches[0];
while((matches=pattern.exec(str))!=null)
{
    last=matches[0];
}
var newStr=str.replace(last, parseInt(last)+1);
console.log(newStr);
```

The code outputs `a-10-b-20-c`

Comment: That looks like PHP, not Javascript.

Comment: :) question was tagged "php" when I opened it for the fitst time

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I had written PHP originally, but what I really wanted was Javascript.

Comment: I think whoever cast the down vote for this answer should remove it now that it has been _translated_ to Javascript.

Comment: @Shawn: Totally agree with you :)